# Jquery Selectbox control with draggable sortable items

Tags: jquery, draggable, drop-down-menu

How to support *dragging items* to change order of elements in JQuery SelectBox control?

```
 <style>
#sortable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#sortable li { margin: 0 3px 3px 3px; padding: 0.4em; padding-left: 1.5em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
#sortable li span { position: absolute; margin-left: -1.3em; }
 #selectable .ui-selecting { background: #FECA40; }
#selectable .ui-selected { background: #F39814; color: white; }
#selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 60%; }
#selectable li { margin: 3px; padding: 0.4em; font-size: 1.4em; height: 18px; }
</style>

$(function() {
$( "#selectable" ).selectable();

$( "#sortable" ).sortable();
$( "#sortable" ).enableSelection();

});

<ol id="selectable">
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
</ol>
<ol id="sortable">
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-widget-content">Item 4</li>
</ol>
```

When I try to use Selection on #sortable, it doesnt work. `$( "#sortable" ).selectable();`

Comment: If you want ANY help show us some code. If possible create a jsfiddle.net for testing purposes. You can't expect people to do your work and spend their time in googling and assuming what your problem might be. What have you tried and what's the part not working?

Comment: Added code to support question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, unless you want to write a custom function on your own the problem is, that there are 2 mouse events on your sortable list. What you can do is adding  `handle` on the sortable function like this:

```
$( "#sortable" )
.sortable({ handle: ".handle" })
.selectable()
```

Now you can use css to place the handle. I found a good example in the jquery forums:
http://jsbin.com/aweyo5/1/edit

Probably the best way to combine those 2 functions.